# cakephp how to save data from dropdownlist into database table

Tags: cakephp, orm, foreign-keys, relational-database, cakephp-2.x

I have created two database tables:

- **sellers_tbls**

  - `id`
  - `business_name`
  - `businesstype_tbls_business_type`
  - `mobile`
- **businesstype_tbls**

  - `id`
  - `business_type`

where `businesstype_tbls` is for displying dropdown types upon registration.

After submitting the form,  `register()` is saving `businesstype_tbls.id` in `sellers_tbls.businesstype_tbls_business_type`.

How can I get `business_type` instead of `id` in my `sellers_tbls`?

My code is as follows:

**register.ctp**

```
<tr>
  <td>Business type</td>
  <td><?php echo $this->Form->select('businesstype_tbls_business_type',$drop);?></td>
</tr>
```

**SellerController**

```
public function register()
{
    $this->loadModel("Seller");

    if($this->Seller->save($this->request->data))
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Successully save your information!');
    }

    $this->loadModel("Businesstype");
    $dt=$this->Businesstype->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','business_type')));
    $this->set('drop',$dt);
}
```

**Model Businesstype.php**

```
class Businesstype extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'businesstype_tbls';
    public $hashMany = 'sellers_tbls';
}
```

**Model Seller.php**

```
class Seller extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'sellers_tbls';
    public $belongsTo = 'businesstype_tbls';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving `businesstype_tbls.id` in `sellers_tbls.businesstype_tbls_business_type` is the expected behavior. This is the whole purpose of setting up relationships between models.

If you wish to store `business_type` in plain text:

1. Remove the relationships
2. Set the type of `sellers_tbls.businesstype_tbls_business_type` to something that can hold the content of `businesstype_tbls.business_type`
3. Set `$dt` to an associative array with every key set to its corresponding value:

   ```
   $dt=$this->Businesstype->find('list',array(
       'fields'=>array('business_type','business_type')
   ));
   ```

Having said this, if you are building a new app and designing the data model from scratch, I recommend that you shorten your table and field names. Your naming strategy is not only complex, but it also doesn't follow CakePHP conventions, which will make your life harder in the long run.

Why not just the following?

- **sellers**

  - `id`
  - `business_name`
  - `businesstype` (or `businesstype_id` if you want to store `businesstypes.id`)
  - `mobile`
- **businesstypes**

  - `id`
  - `type`